# TextField type to Show Button in javafx

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

I am trying Show a Button on TextField look like Windows 8 Metro theme in javafx.

> If TextField is empty button is invisible otherwise button show.

In this stage i'm little close to success. i use this code to make it.

```
@FXML
private TextField tfMyName;//fx:id="tfMyName"
@FXML
private Button btnClear;//fx:id="btnClear"

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    clearTextFieldByButton(tfMyName, btnClear);
}

public void clearTextFieldByButton(TextField value, Button btn){

    btn.setVisible(false);

    value.setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            if ((value.textProperty().get().length() < 0) || (value.textProperty().get().equals(""))) {
                btn.setVisible(false);
            } else if (value.textProperty().get().length() > -1 || (!value.textProperty().get().equals(""))) {
                btn.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            tfMyName.clear();
            btn.setVisible(false);
            tfMyName.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```

Using this code by default button is invisible but the button is only visible when i type **more then one Characters**.
But i need if anything input into the TextField to Button show.

But when i remove the condition under KeyEvent replace by

```
value.setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            btn.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Then btn show if any character input into the TextField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also prefer to use JavaFX binding mechanism:

```
@Override
public void start( final Stage primaryStage )
{
    TextField textfield = new TextField();
    Button button = new Button( "my button" );
    button.visibleProperty().bind( textfield.textProperty().isEmpty().not() );

    final Scene scene = new Scene( new HBox( button, textfield ), 800, 600 );
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

The actual problem in your code:
You have attached a listener to field when "OnKeyTyped", at this stage the newly typed text is not appended to the textfield's text value so your if-else condition will not see it. Instead, the correct way should be attaching the listener on "OnKeyReleased".

Comment: Problem solve with OnKeyReleased. 
Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Add a listener to the [`textProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#textProperty--) of the TextField. Check if the value is empty, hide the button else show it. It will be called whenever a character is added or removed from the textfield.

Here is a MCVE, you can just add the listener to the initialize method of the controller.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HideButtonOnTextEntered extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        Button button = new Button("Button");
        button.setVisible(false);
        VBox root = new VBox(20, textField, button);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        textField.textProperty().addListener((ov, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue.isEmpty()) {
                button.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                button.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```